# Action not Found in flows

Tags: visual-workflow

I have created a process builder and trying to call a flow from it. But it is showing me an error that action not found. please help me her

Comment: Is the flow you are trying to call activated?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without more information, but it is probable that your Flow is not an autolaunched flow.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_admin_flow_type.htm&language=en_US

> This flow type doesn’t support screens, steps, choices, or dynamic
>   choices.

If you have any of these items in your flow, they will have to be removed. Even if they are not being used anywhere, it will still not show as autolaunched if any of them are present.